# how to make dynamic menu module from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hi i am making a menu module whose menu items will be fetched from the database. i have two tables in the database which names are main_module and second is sub_module. i have a primary key "module_id" in the main_module table and this is foreign key in second table.

the columns of first main_module table are

```
module_id
module_name
```

and for sub_module table the columns are

```
main_module_id(F)
sub_module_id
sub_module_name
```

the data in first table are

```
1 Home
2 Conf
```

and data in second table are

```
1   1   dashboard
1   2   bulletin board
2   3   site configuration
2   4   meta data
```

now i want to populate these items dynamically in a css menu. so how to do this. please help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have connected to the database, and retrieved the data, you can loop the result inside a ul tag:

echo "<ul>"; 
 while($each_row=$result->fetch_row())  // this is the object version; 
      { 
        echo '<li><a href="whatever the link is">' . $each_row[index_of_needed_column] . "</a></li>"; 
       } 
echo "</ul>" 
That will ensure the navigation is created. If you want to float or do any styling to it, add a class to the ul, and just style it accordingly. 
That rough sample should give you something with which to start